# Isolated scope built in directives in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolated-scope

I was reading about the isolated scopes in AngularJs. I was wondering that are there any built-in directives in AngularJs that uses isolated scope. Could you please provide some useful link or mention some names if anyone came across such question?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could probably search the AngularJS codebase for "scope: {" or something similar

Comment: The core AngularJS directives use either *no* scope or *inherited* scope. None of them use *isolate* scope. For the list of directives that use inherited scope, see [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs).

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg . Perfect link to answer the question.